Folder / Domain selection
I am working on selecting “folders/domains” for an IT product: in this filter you can select domains and subdomains which contain elements.
The parent domain Finance contains x elements + a sub-domain Marketing which contains y elements.

Now I need to be able to select the following options:

All Finance and Marketing sub-domain (all elements).
Only the Marketing sub-domain (with its y elements).
these are simple the option that complicates everything is the third one
Only the elements of Finance

How can this type of selection be handled in a simple way? The problem is that this is not a "file system" type of thing and I cannot show all the "file/element" inside each folder/domain.

"The parent domain Finance contains x elements + a sub-domain Marketing." That is not what appears in the image, Finance and Marketing are on the same level, in other words, Marketing is not indented to the right of Finance.

So it sounds like while elements can all contain sub-elements, only some of them can be expanded to further sub-select individual items, is that right? What distinguishes items that CAN be expanded and show their contents vs. those that cannot? I know you explained that it is not a file system, but it is a bit confusing to me that Finance shows 38 sub-items, but when expanded it only shows one (presumably the one that contains further sub-elements). Why are only certain items expandable? Your clarifications will make it easier to give you suggestions that might help - thanks!

@Mattynabib that's the point: Finance is a group of items that I cannot display + other sub-groups which can be displayed (but their items are not displayed as well). So imagine a circle named Finance that contains 35 items and another circle named Risk with 3 items: in the tree I need to display only the circle names but users should be able to select just the items contained in Finance

Ok, I see, you want the option to select all of the non-visible items in Finance and NOT select the whole Risk circle.
You could use a simple "partially selected" checkbox pattern to indicate that the user has selected everything in the folder except the unchecked thing - though it would not be quite so simple in this case. To get there the user would have to first select the parent (thus selecting everything within) and then de-select the sub-domain (thus leaving a bunch of invisible objects selected, which is a little unusual and unclear for the user):

Additionally if they wanted to then deselect everything, following common patterns they would have to click the Finance checkbox again, which would re-select all, then click it AGAIN to deselect all. Kind of a lot of clicking, but this might work.
Perhaps instead you need a way within a domain it indicate how many non-subdomain objects there are and to select them explicitly, maybe something like this:

Off the top of my head these seem like two viable options... I lean towards the second one because it makes things clearer for the user - the "invisible" items are rendered as "visible" and selectable so it is less of a mystery.

thanks so much for your answer and by the way the second option you proposed is the one we are using for the time being...and we decided to check it with real users after we release it and see if it is easily understandable. Thanks!!!
